# ImportJSON Function results not working with other cell formulas

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

When using the importJSON function in a cell am I able to use this cell in other cell formulas?

Example: Cell A1 contains =importJSON("url", "/name", "noHeaders"),1,1) which displays a value of 100.

Can I then use this in a formula in Cell B1? Example: Cell B1 formula =IF(AND(A1 > 50), "Y", "N")). Currently the formula doesn't work. How am I able to check is the importJSON result is an actual number or string?

Comment: `````=type()`````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `VALUE` formula:

```
=IF(AND(VALUE(A1) > 50), "Y", "N"))
```

This will convert the string into a *number* and the `IF` condition will become possible.

However, if you just want to solely find out the *type* of data passed into the function, you will have to use `TYPE` on the cell.

This will return, according to the [documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3267375), one of the following:

> - **1**: if value is a number
> - **2**: if value is text
> - **4**: if value is boolean
> - **16**: if value is an error
> - **64**: if value is an array
> - **128**: for any other type of cell. For example, in-cell images and sparklines.

It's also important to keep the following in mind as well:

> The function cannot determine whether or not a cell or range of cells is using a formula, it can only return the type of value being displayed in the cells.

#### Reference

- [VALUE Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094220);
- [TYPE Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3267375).

Comment: Why ```AND()```?